# В чем смысл автозагрузки классов, если все равно нужно использовать импорт?

Tags: php, ооп, composer, автозагрузка

В данный момент изучаю автозагрузку и пространство имен и назрел вопрос, в чем смысл автозагрузки? Eсли все равно перед созданием экземпляра класса нужно импортировать его?

Comment: В php нет никакого импорта. Есть либо `include\require` для файлов и `use` для пространств имен.

Comment: в том чтобы поставить с соответствие ваши "импортируемые" классы и пути в файловой системе может?

Comment: Почитайте для чего вообще нужно пространство имён. Если кратко, то это надо для того, чтобы все ваши классы "разложить по полочкам". А include/require - чтобы подключить php-файл к приложению. Иначе при попытке использовать класс, который не подключен к приложению, у вас просто будет ошибка, что такого класса не существует